# How do I mark a UIKit class or method as deprecated?

Tags: ios, warnings, clang, deprecated

I'm using a security framework in iOS that doesn't work with `UIDocumentInteractionController`. I want other developers to get a warning if they try to use this class. I've tried the following, and it doesn't work. Any ideas?

**MyApp.pch**

```
#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "UIDocumentInteractionController+JVAdditions.h"
#endif
```

**UIDocumentInteractionController+Additions.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UIDocumentInteractionController ()

+ (UIDocumentInteractionController *)interactionControllerWithURL:(NSURL *)url __attribute__((deprecated));

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#pragma GCC poison interactionControllerWithURL
```

Note the lack of a colon. Poison is designed to work with C symbols, not Objective-C selectors. However, it will do what you need here.

(The pragma was introduced in GCC but clang supports it too, BTW).